# How to add region to config for AWS Amplify when adding API to project

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to follow the [AWS Tutorial for iOS](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/start?ref=amplify-iOS-btn).  However, when adding the GraphQL API I keep getting an error: "An error occurred when pushing the resources to the cloud **Missing Region in config**."  This occurs when running sudo amplify push after adding the api to "update resources in the cloud." [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKLxi.png)

I tried adding a Region key-value pair to my awsconfiguration.json but still received the same behavior:

```js
{
    "UserAgent": "aws-amplify/cli",
    "Version": "0.1.0",
    "Region": "us-east-1",
    "IdentityManager": {
        "Default": {}
    }
}
```

I wasn't able to find any useful info with a google search or here in stack overflow.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing the **amplify-cli** did you run `amplify configure` or `amplify configure project`?

This should prompt you to login in your aws console and also asks you to specify a region.

Comment: No, I’ll try that. Do you know the file location of the config file?

Comment: If you have the **aws-cli** already installed and set up you can usually skip this step. All it does is basically setting up the **aws-cli** for you. So it creates the config files in the default location for the **aws-cli** which is `~/.aws/config`